# Almost packages are removed when install with npm (React) by Create-react-app

Tags: node.js, npm

I installed `create-react-app` with `npm` and it automatically installed `yarn` when I create project (or I installed yarn before, but I tried to uninstall yarn but it is still installed when creating project). `yarn.lock` and `package.json` were created. When I install any packages, it will remove almost all packages. Then `npm start` does not work any more.

[image]

Comment: But 'yarn add' is working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have yarn installed by default by create-react-app. In this case, you should be careful to only use “yarn add” (not “npm install”) in the future. Otherwise, npm deletes everything. (Known issue with yarn)

Issue discussion:
https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5240

Comment: Thanks very much for your help :D